# Can I take away permission from a specific user in the command setfacL?

Tags: permissions, acl

I know that this setfacl is to give permission:

```
setfacl -m u:user:rwx myfolder
```

But is there one to take permissions such as:

```
setfacl -m u:user:-rwx myfolder
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can specify `-` in the relevant permission field to set an ACL with restricted permissions:

```
setfacl -m u:user:--- myfolder
```

This doesn’t work to restrict the permissions of the owner, which makes sense since the owner of a file can change the ACLs anyway. It does work to restrict the permissions of a non-owner user who would otherwise have access to the file (through group or “other” permissions).